# Where to get a pre-built Chromium to easily do modifications?

Tags: browser, build, compilation, linker, chromium

Chromium takes too long to get compiled, like **7 hours** on a regular powerful desktop. I'm thinking of some where to get a **pre-built Chromium**, with which I will be able to compile again only some files to re-link to make a new Chromium binary.

Possible to **compile just some source code files** and **re-link** (re-link object files)?

Comment: I doubt you will be find compiled Chromium anywhere cause the size of the folder holding it would be too big because of debug symbols, object files etc. If I remember correctly, even the size of Release build folder is more than 20 GB.

Comment: oh mamma mia, 20GB? oh mine :(

Comment: Here are sizes of the folder from our Chromium fork version 78: Release 64-bit: 22.4 GB (24,105,542,263 bytes), Debug 64-bit: 70.6 GB (75,855,436,588 bytes). Though it's a modified fork but you will get around the same size or a few MB smaller, even if you compile untouched Chromium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to build Chromium from source but it's every easy to build a new browser based on Chromium.

With GitHub Electron, any app based on it is a real Chromium browser, and developers may create custom UI for their Electron-based browsers.

However, modern browsers would require having servers for storing users' sync data, this might not be easily affordable for 1-man development army to create a new browser for the mass.

Electron app is a pack of Chromium sandbox, and Node.js backend, the 2 communicate thru' IPC as Node.js will be able to access all resources.

GitHub Electron:
https://electronjs.org